# Telling omake to use static version of a c library

Tags: ocaml, protobuf-c, omake

I'm using omake to build a native binary executable. After it links and i try to run it, it fails to run giving the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf-c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Is there a way, at compile time, to tell the executable to pick up the static version: libprotobuf-c.a and not the shared on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a global flag that can be passed to ld, the linker, that enforces the linker prefer static libraries to dynamic ones when available. In my case, I set the library name explicitly like so:

`OCAML_LINK_FLAGS += -cclib -l:libprotobuf-c.a`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `omake` but I believe flag to `ocamlc` you are looking for is `dllpath`:

```
   -dllpath dir
          Adds  the  directory dir to the run-time search path for shared C libraries.  At link-
          time, shared libraries are searched in the standard search path (the one corresponding
          to  the  -I option).  The -dllpath option simply stores dir in the produced executable
          file, where ocamlrun(1) can find it and use it.
```

If you can configure `omake` to pass the appropriate `-dllpath` argument to ocamlc, you should be good to go.

Under the hood I believe this is using the `rpath` feature (runtime library search path) of `ld`, the GNU linker. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld .  There is also a `chrpath` utility to change the `rpath` of an already-built executable.

Another option is running your executable with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set so that the shared library is on the load path.  You could also install the shared library system wide if appropriate.  A final option is to load the library manually when your application boots using `dlopen`.

The correct choice depends on how you will distribute this and to who you will distribute this, if at all.  Keep in mind if you use `rpath`/`dllpath` the end user is unlikely to have `protobuf` installed in the same location you do.

Comment: It looks like you answered the previous version of my question. I modified it.